# Convert WHERE clause with OR operators into CASE

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

The solution could be really simple, but perhaps it has been too much work for today or I am just dumb and can't solve it myself at this moment, but I really need it right now.

So let's say I've got query like this:

```
DECLARE @input BIT
SELECT A
FROM T1
WHERE (@input = 1 AND A = 3) OR (@input = 0 AND (A = 3 OR A <> 3))
```

I would like to use `CASE` within where clause where if input parameter equals to `1` it should restrict to only some values of column `A` and if it equals to `0`, all values should be allowed.

I was thinking that I should use a case statement without `ELSE` part:

```
CASE WHEN @input = 1 THEN A = 3 END
```

but in `THEN` part it expects result and not another condition.

Comment: `CASE` expressions don't belong in the `WHERE` clause. Are you merely looking for `WHERE (@input = 1 AND A = 3) OR @input = 0` maybe? What do you want a `CASE`expression for? What do you think would you gain by it?

Comment: can you provide sample data and expected output. that shall help

Comment: @ThorstenKettner That's one solution! Thanks. Now I've got another dilemma. Which one will work faster, yours or the answer JohnWoo have posted?

Comment: It shouldn't make any difference. As mentioned you wouldn't introduce `CASE` expressions in the `WHERE` clause, because they are meant to create a boolean evaluation, which the `WHERE` clause already does anyway. You mentioned that there may be multiple values you'd be looking for, so check `for WHERE (@input = 1 AND A IN (1,2,3)) OR @input = 0`. Do the same with a `CASE` expression. You'll see that the mere `AND`/`OR` solution is more readable.

Comment: Actually, in this example, the simplest where clause would be `WHERE A = 3 OR @Input != 1`...

Comment: @Zohar Peled: You are right. I was still over-complicating this.

Comment: @ZoharPeled Yea, since it's `BIT` , it can have only two values 0 and 1. Great!

Comment: @ThorstenKettner Edited my comment, first version assumed `@input` is not null... I've fallen to the same pit I've warned John Woo from :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
WHERE A = CASE WHEN @input = 1 THEN 3 ELSE A END
```

Comment: thank you, that's what I was looking for! Can you check my comment under the question?

Comment: @nikname that one you have to check in the execution plan. it is hard to gues it here.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I'm gonna pick your answer in few minutes.

Comment: Note that if A is nullable, it will not return null values in case `@input` != 1.

Comment: @ZoharPeled I have forgotten about that, but since I don't need `NULL` values at this moment it won't be a problem. But thanks, I should probably think about that next time.

Answer (score 1):

for SQL 2012+

```
WHERE A = IIF(@input = 1,3,A)
```

Answer (score 1):

So, let's brake this code apart:

```
DECLARE @input BIT
SELECT A
FROM T1
WHERE (@input = 1 AND A = 3) OR (@input = 0 AND (A = 3 OR A <> 3))
```

The `A = 3 OR A <> 3` will always evaluate to `true`, so it's meaningless. Let's remove it.

```
WHERE (@input = 1 AND A = 3) OR @input = 0
```

Since `@input` is a bit, it can only have either `0`, `1`, or `null` - so we can simplify it even further:

```
WHERE @input != 1 OR A = 3
```

Now, if `@input = 1`, only records where `A = 3`  will be returned, and if `@input = 0`, or if `@input is null`, all records will be returned.

So the full script becomes this:

```
DECLARE @input BIT
SELECT A
FROM T1
WHERE @input != 1 OR A = 3
```

Much simpler and more elegant then using a `case` expression, IMHO...